# Magento: How to sort products newest first "disregarding category"?

Tags: magento, sorting, categories

I've tried this and it partially works

http://www.dconstructing.com/2011/04/07/sort-magento-catalog-by-date-added/

But on a page that has multiple categories, it sorts categories as first level, and only then it sorts products within each category.

So an earlier product in a category comes before a later product in another category. I don't want that. I want a flat sorting that only sorts by "position" (magento term) regardless of the category.

How can I achieve that?

Comment: This cannot be done in layout XML. You will need work with the catalog/layer object if you want toolbar etc to work correctly.

Comment: Ben, out of curiosity, why can't you use: <action method="addOrderToAvailableOrders"><order>created_at</order><name>Newest</name></action>  inside the toolbar block definition inside category.xml?

Comment: @pspahn I don't understand your comment, OP is asking for position, not `created_at`?

Comment: You said it can't be done in layout, but per my answer (I guess Guerra removed his), you can use addOrderToAvailableOrders() in toolbar.phtml to set a new attribute to sort by (in his case, 'created_at' to sort by newest product according to created date). Why doesn't attaching this method in the toolbar block definition in catalog.xml also work (via <action method="addOrderToAvailableOrders">)?

Comment: create_at is fine, as long as they sort latest-first

Answer (score 1):

This instruction work for me with the same problem product sorting. I used the third one [Magento Sort by Newest Products Solution](http://magento2x.com/magento-sort-newest-products-solution/)

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively to Guerra's answer, while inside toolbar.phtml you can use:

```
<?php if($this->getCurrentDirection() == 'desc') : ?>
    <?php $this->addOrderToAvailableOrders('created_at','Newest') ?>
<?php else : ?>
    <?php $this->addOrderToAvailableOrders('created_at','Oldest') ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: To Achieve this copy the file `Toolbar.php` from `app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/List/Toolbar.php`. Create a Directory Structure in local and paste the `Toolbar.php` as shown below `app/code/local/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/List/Toolbar.php`

Step 2: Around line 232 you should see the below code in `setCollection()` function

```
if ($this->getCurrentOrder()) {
  $this->_collection->setOrder($this->getCurrentOrder(), $this->getCurrentDirection());
}
```

Replace the above code with the new code given below

```
if ($this->getCurrentOrder()) {
  if(($this->getCurrentOrder())=='position'){
      $this->_collection->setOrder('entity_id','desc');
  }
  else {
   $this->_collection->setOrder($this->getCurrentOrder(),$this->getCurrentDirection());
  }
}
```